# OCaml syntax error in recursive function

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm writing a function that take a pair of lists, if the length of two lists are equal then create a pair of each element from each list, but my function doesn't work and the compiler say there is a syntax error

Could someone explain why there is a syntax error at the semicolon at the end of my function?

This is my code:

```
let define_tuple a b =
(a, b);;

let zip (a, b) =
if List.length (fst (a, b)) != List.length (fst (a, b)) 
then
printf_string "lengths of 2 lists need to be equal"
else
let rec create_tuples (a, b) = 
if List.length (List.tl (fst (a, b))) = 0 && List.length (List.tl (snd (a, b))) != 0
then 
[]
else
List.append define_tuple (List.hd (fst (a, b))) (List.hd (snd (a, b))) create_tuples (List.tl (fst (a, b)), List.tl (snd (a, b)));;



zip ([1; 2; 3], [2; 3; 4]);;
```

Comment: You really need to learn to indent your code or use an editor that does it for you.

Comment: currently i'm using Typerex, which is here: http://www.typerex.org/

Comment: @TrungBún you should use emacs + Tuareg, much much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few possible improvements and errors in your code and I list them all in the following:

**No. 1**

If you write your code in a file and try to compile / run your file, then you don't need `;;` in the end for every function.

**No. 2**

`let define_tuple a b = (a, b);;`

You don't need to define such a function, instead, you can directly use `(a, b)`.

**No. 3**

```
let zip (a, b) =
  if List.length (fst (a, b)) != List.length (fst (a, b)) then
    printf_string "lengths of 2 lists need to be equal"
  else
    let rec create_tuples (a, b) = 
      if List.length (List.tl (fst (a, b))) = 0 && List.length (List.tl (snd (a, b))) != 0
      then 
    []
      else
    List.append define_tuple (List.hd (fst (a, b))) (List.hd (snd (a, b))) create_tuples (List.tl (fst (a, b)), List.tl (snd (a, b)));;
```

**3.1**

For your first `if ... else ...`, it is not correct as the `if` branch returns `unit` and `else` branch returns `list`.

In OCaml, `if` and `else` or any branch of pattern matching should returns the same type.

**3.2**

Because of **3.1**, I suggest you write an exception for the `non-equal lengths` case. In this way, the whole function still returns list and code is more readable and users of your function can also get the chance to "catch" your exception case.

**3.3**

for function `create_tuples`,

```
let rec create_tuples (a, b) = 
      if List.length (List.tl (fst (a, b))) = 0 && List.length (List.tl (snd (a, b))) != 0
      then 
    []
      else
    List.append define_tuple (List.hd (fst (a, b))) (List.hd (snd (a, b))) create_tuples (List.tl (fst (a, b)), List.tl (snd (a, b)));;
```

**3.3.1**

`List.length (List.tl (fst (a, b))) = 0`

You don't need to use `fst (a,b)`, instead, just `a` is enough because a is already known.

It is the same for your `snd` usage.

Basically you don't need `fst` and `snd` all over your code.

**3.3.1.1**

You should check whether `a` and `b`'s lengths are 0 or not, not the `tl` of them.

**3.3.2**

You also don't need `(a,b)` a tuple as the parameters for `create_tuples`, instead, you can use `create_tuples a b`. It is better because your code doesn't need to create a tuple for a pair of parameters.

**3.3.3**

`List.append define_tuple (List.hd (fst (a, b))) (List.hd (snd (a, b))) create_tuples (List.tl (fst (a, b)), List.tl (snd (a, b)))`

First of all, `List.append` is to append one list to another list. In your case, you are adding an element to a list, so you should use `::`.

You should use `()` to include a function application if you want the value of the function application to be used.

for example, you should do `(define_tuple (List.hd (fst (a, b))) (List.hd (snd (a, b)))):: (create_tuples (List.tl (fst (a, b)), List.tl (snd (a, b))))`.

If you consider the previous points together, you can do

`(List.hd a, List.hd b)::(create_tuples (List.tl a) (List.tl b))`

**3.4**

You have defined function `create_tuples`, but did you really use it in your code? No.

So at the end, you should do

`in create_tuples a b`

**No. 4**

You should use `<>` to check inequality.

---

The full refined/corrected code is

```
exception Non_equal_list_length

let zip a b =
  if List.length a <> List.length b then raise Non_equal_list_length
  else
    let rec create_tuples a b = 
      if List.length a = 0 && List.length b = 0 then []
      else (List.hd a, List.hd b)::(create_tuples (List.tl a) (List.tl b))
    in
    create_tuples a b
```

---

Some more improvements:

- You can use pattern matching directly on lists
- You should always take tail-recursive in consideration

Final improved code:

```
exception Non_equal_list_length

let zip a b =
    let rec zipping acc = function
      | [], [] -> List.rev acc
      | hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2 -> zipping ((hd1,hd2)::acc) (tl1,tl2)
      | _ -> raise Non_equal_list_length
    in
    zipping [] (a,b)
```

Comment: Such a great answer! I'm a beginner in Ocaml and I learnt so much from this! Thank you!

Comment: @TrungBún can you pls mark my answer as corrected, so I can earn the score?

Comment: @TrungBún also you should buy the book of real world ocaml or read free on its website: https://realworldocaml.org/

Answer (score 1):

The expression `let a = b` is valid only at the topmost level of a module, where it defines names to be exported from the module. Everywhere else this expression is used to introduce a local variable (or variables), and it has the form `let a = b in c`. You're missing the `in` keyword, and the expression in which you want to use your local variable `create_tuples`.

(There are some other errors that you will find when you get the syntax in order.)

**Update**

Here's a simple example of a function that uses a helper function declared with `let a = b in c`:

```
let myrev l =
    let rec irev sofar = function
    | [] -> sofar
    | hd :: tl -> irev (hd :: sofar) tl
    in
    irev [] l
```